# How to style the third word inside of a div and use that text in part of the new code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, text

```
<span class="myclass">
    one two three
</span>
<span class="myclass">
    four fix six
</span>
<span class="myclass">
    seven eight nine
</span>
```

So I have this working code which styles the first word.

```
    $('.myclass').each(function() {
        var word = $(this).html();
        var index = word.indexOf(' ');
        if(index == -1) {
            index = word.length;
        }
        $(this).html('<span class="aspanclass2">' + word.substring(0, index) + '</span>' + word.substring(index, word.length));
    });
```

That code results in this, which is just what I want for the first word:

```
<span class="myclass">
    <span class="aspanclass2">one</span> two three
</span>
<span class="myclass">
    <span class="aspanclass2">four</span> five six
</span>
<span class="myclass">
    <span class="aspanclass2">seven</span> eight nine
</span>
```

---

---

However, I also need to style the third word. Moreover, I want to use the text from the third word as part of the styling to add to it, so it looks like this in the end:

```
<span class="myclass">
    <span class="aspanclass2">one</span> two <a href="http://zzzzz.com/three">three</a>
</span>
<span class="myclass">
    <span class="aspanclass2">four</span> five <a href="http://zzzzz.com/six">six</a>
</span>
<span class="myclass">
    <span class="aspanclass2">seven</span> eight <a href="http://zzzzz.com/nine">nine</a>
</span>
```

I tried a couple things but it isn't working. Please help.

*(THIRD WORD, not the second word. Also, the text CHANGES, it is not just the text "six" or "nine", it changes on every page reload. So just the third word NOT that irrelevant link that talks about replacing a word with a different word.)*

Comment: No I need THIRD word not the second one.

Comment: You could use the same technique to select the third word.

Comment: No. I already tried that before I made this post. It is not relevant. That post has NOTHING to do with this post, that cost is about replacing a word with another word, which will NOT work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually use `split` to break your `span` text into an array of the individual words, manipulate the individual elements and join it back up and add it back into the DOM -

```js
$('.myclass').each(function(index, me) {
  var words = $(me).text().trim().split(' ');
  words[0] = '<span class="aspanclass2">' + words[0] + '</span>';
  words[2] = '<a href="http://zzzzz.com/' + words[2] + '">' + words[2] + '</a>';
  $(me).html(words.join(' '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="myclass">
    one two three
</span>
<span class="myclass">
    four fix six
</span>
<span class="myclass">
    seven eight nine
</span>
```

Comment: Looks like it will work. I will try it and get back to you.

Comment: PERFECT! Does exactly what I need, plus this code is very flexible so I can style as many words as I want! Thank you! :D :D

Comment: @wannaknow No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. This solution should work with any number of words.

```
<span class="myclass">one two three</span>
<span class="myclass">four fix six</span>
<span class="myclass">seven eight nine</span>

<script>
    $('.myclass').each(function() {
    var word = $(this).html().split(" ");

    $(this).html('<span class="aspanclass2">' + word[0] + '</span> ' + word.slice(1, word.length-1).join(" ") + ' <a href="http://zzzzz.com/'+ word[word.length-1] +'">'+ word[word.length-1] + '</a></span>');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple try with replace, example:

```
var string = 'test three words tttt';
alert(string.replace(/(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)/, '$1 $2 <i>$3</i>'));
```

Comment: This would require knowing the text beforehand, not just selecting whatever the third word is.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you assigning some ids/class to the third word as well?

```
 lastindex = word.lastIndexOf(' ');
 $(this).html('<span class="aspanclass2">' + word.substring(0, index) + '</span>' + word.substring(index, lastindex) + '<span class="something">' + word.substring(lastindex,word.length) + '</span>');
```

Also, consider using createElement.

Comment: This might work but I can't be sure because John C's answer already worked for me. Also, I didn't bother assigning an id or class because when I know the code it's easy to add in at any time, and yes, I did add a class to the new link.